# Outlook 2010 Hidden contacts

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010

I just realized that i have a problem with Outlook 2010. I can't see my contact folders for an e-mail account, just the personal contacts folder.

The single modification that I've done was adding a exchange account.
If i search the contacts they are found, but i can't see the folders.

Anyone had similar problems?

Comment: if you try and re-add these folders does outlook tell you that they already exists ?

Comment: I wanted to try, but the folders are shown in the list where i select the place of the new folder. now they just appeared. strage... thanks for the help